# Multiple "AND" , "OR" conditions and reference adjacent cells in Excel 2016

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have an excel sheet which has two worksheets,

Worksheet 1 is the dashboard and Worksheet 2 is the Data Sheet.In worksheet 2 I have

```
     A               B         C          D        E          F             G
Customer ID         date       R    Transaction payment  Recency Score  Frequency Score Monetary Score
20000679742      28-03-2017   100         15    1280225         1                  3              3
```

The formula I am using in the Worksheet 1 is :

```
=IF(OR(DATA!G2 =1,DATA!G2=2),AND(OR(DATA!H2=4,DATA!H2=3)),"DATA!B2")
```

it is returning **TRUE** instead of the Value in the *B2 cell* in DATA Sheet, B2 is the Customer ID

what am I doing wrong? Any Idea??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you'll need to remove the quotes from `"DATA!B2"`.  Then I believe you want to return B2 if G2 is equal to either 1 or 2 **AND** H2 is equal to either 3 or 4.  Otherwise, leave the cell blank.  If so, try...

```
=IF(AND(OR(DATA!G2 =1,DATA!G2=2),OR(DATA!H2=4,DATA!H2=3)),DATA!B2,"")
```

Comment: @A.S.H I'm sure you'll return the favor next time.  :-)

Comment: :) Thank you so much :') @Domenic.